# Prove every filter is contained in an ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, filters

By Zorn's lemma, let $M$ be an maximal element in $P=\{G\mid F\subseteq G\}$ where $F$ is a filter on $X$ and $X$ is a non-empty set. Clearly $M$ is also a filter on $X$ by closure under supersets, as $F$ is a filter.

Let $A\subseteq X$. Suppose for a contradiction $A\notin M$ and $X-A\notin M$.

If $A\in F$, then $A\in M$ as $F\subseteq M$. Contradiction.

If $A\notin F$, and $A=\emptyset$, then $X-A \in M$. Contradiction.

But how can I show that in the case of $A\notin F$ and $A\neq\emptyset$, there is a contradiction?

Comment: What is your definition of ultrafilter? Mine is a maximal filter. Yours seems to be: for any set $A$, either $A$ or its complement is in the filter. Here you have to prove one direction of this equivalence.

Answer (score 3):

You're approaching this wrong. If $F$ wasn't an ultrafilter, then there will be some $A\in M\setminus F$. So it shouldn't be possible to derive contradiction from the condition $A\notin F$ and $A\neq\varnothing$.

The key point is the following lemma, which you should probably prove if you haven't proved it yet:

> **Lemma.** Suppose that $F$ is a filter on a set $X$ and $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\notin F$ and $X\setminus A\notin F$. Then $F\cup\{A\}$ can be extended to a filter.

Using the lemma we can now appeal to the maximality of $M$ to ensure that for every $A$, either $A\in M$ or $X\setminus A\in M$.

Answer (score 3):

> **Fact** Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on a set $X$. If $A \subseteq X$ is such that $A \notin \mathcal{F}$ and $X\setminus A \notin \mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F} \cup \{A\}$ generates a filter $\mathcal{F}' \supseteq \mathcal{F}$ with $A \in \mathcal{F'}$.

Proof: Let $F \in \mathcal{F}$. If $F \cap A = \emptyset$ then $F \subseteq X\setminus A$, and so $X\setminus A \in \mathcal{F}$ contradiction. So

$$ \forall F \in \mathcal{F}: F \cap A \neq \emptyset$$

Then define 
$$\mathcal{F'} = \{ C \subseteq X: \exists F \in \mathcal{F}: A \cap F \subseteq C\}$$

Claim: $\mathcal{F'}$ is a filter:

1. $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}'$ by the above intersection property.
2. If $C_1, C_2 \in \mathcal{F}'$ then let $F_1 ,F_2\in \mathcal{F}$ be such that $F_i\cap A \subseteq C_i$ for $i=1,2$.
   But then $F_1 \cap F_2 \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A \cap (F_1 \cap F_2) = (A \cap F_1) \cap (A \cap F_2) \subseteq C_1 \cap C_2$, so $C_1 \cap C_2 \in \mathcal{F}'$.
3. Finally if $C \in \mathcal{F'}$ and $C \subseteq D$, then we have $F \in \mathcal{F}$ with $A \cap F \subseteq C \subseteq D$, so $D \in \mathcal{F}'$.

And clearly all $F \in \mathcal{F}$ are in $\mathcal{F}'$ as we just take $F$ itself in the definition, and note $F \cap A \subseteq F$.
In the same way, $X \cap A = A \in \mathcal{F}'$ as well. That concludes the proof.

Now, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a maximal filter (by Zorn), then let $A \subseteq X$. 
If $A \notin \mathcal{F}$ and $X\setminus A \notin \mathcal{F}$ the above fact produces a filter $\mathcal{F}'$ that is strictly larger tahn $\mathcal{F}$ (as $A \in \mathcal{F}'\setminus \mathcal{F}$, contradicting maximality. 
So one of the alternatives $A \in \mathcal{F}$ or $X\setminus A \in \mathcal{F}$ must hold, as required.